# how to force TransformationFunctions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, term-rewriting

I have this function:

```
F[z_, y_, θ_] = Sqrt[3]/(2*π)*w^2/z^2 * 
 Exp[-w^2*(θ^2/z - 3*y*θ/z^2 + 3*y^2/z^3)]
```

I want to calculate

```
FT[ψ, θ5] = 
 Simplify[
   z3*F[z3, y3 - θ1*z3, θ3 - θ1] *
    F[z5 - z3, y5 - θ3*(z5 - z3) - y3, θ5 - θ3] *
    1 / (Sqrt[2 π] Subscript[σ, b]) *
    Exp[-(α + θ1)/(2*Subscript[σ, b]^2)], 
   TransformationFunctions -> {
     c = (a + b)/2, 
     θ13 = 2*z3/w^2, θ35 = 2*(z5 - z3)/w^2
   }
  ]
```

using TransformationFunctions to redifine the output. It is not clear to me why TransformationFunctions is not applied to the output. Could anyone help me ?

Thank you

Andrea

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! You can solve `θ13 == 2*z3/w^2, θ35 == 2*(z5 - z3)/w^2` for `z3` and `z5`, then substitute these in your long expression and simplify.

Comment: `TransformationFunctions` must be functions. You are giving expressions that should be supplied as `Assumptions`. (But use `==` not `=`)

Comment: Unfortunately, `Simplify[..., Assumptions->{θ13 == 2*z3/w^2, θ35 == 2*(z5 - z3)/w^2}]` has no effect, that is the reason I suggested to use substitution.